# ValueError: Expected object or value <-> Can't load a json file to pandas dataframe, or convert to csv, either will suffice

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have an approx 1.5 GB sized JSON file that I need to use as a dataframe, and I've tried my all out for 10 hours straight to get it load as a dataframe, going through all possible answered questions on StackOverflow too! As a second option I tried to convert it to csv and then load it as dataframe, but that also fails, as well as in previously answered questions people just explained the error rather than giving the code, here is how the json looks like:

```
{'work': '2505753', 'flags': [], 'unixtime': 1260403200, 'stars': 1.0, 'nhelpful': 0, 'time': 'Dec 10, 2009', 'comment': "I really thought that I would like this book. I'm fascinated by this time period, and the plots to assassinate Hitler have always intrigued me. However, this book was so boring that I had to force myself to read it. The author no doubt has a commanding vocabulary, but his writing style and word choices made the book a chore to read. I've read dry textbooks that had more life to them than this novel. ", 'user': 'schatzi'}
{'work': '12458291', 'flags': [], 'unixtime': 1361664000, 'stars': 4.0, 'nhelpful': 0, 'time': 'Feb 24, 2013', 'comment': "After her father's death, Lena discovers that her father had been keeping many secrets from her. Lena is a member of the. Silenti, telepaths who came to our world through a portal. She must learn to navigate through the social, religious, and political pitfalls of her new life. Who can she trust? What will her role be? I enjoyed this story and the world the author created very much. ", 'user': 'aztwinmom'}
```

I tried this code as a 2nd option to convert to csv, the error I debugged was of single quote, but replacing `"\'"` with `"\""` in this huge data will take enormous time.

### Attempt with json

```
import json
import csv
import os

f = open('test.json')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()

f = open('data.json')
csv_file = csv.writer(f)
count=0
for item in data:
    f.writerow(item)
    count+=1
    if(count==10):
        break

f.close()
```

#### Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-d75bae392cae> in <module>
      1 f = open('test.json')
----> 2 data = json.load(f)
      3 f.close()

e:\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 296         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297 
    298 

e:\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

e:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

e:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    351         """
    352         try:
--> 353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
    355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

- `pd.read_json('test.json')` results in:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-771e17311e28> in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_json('test.json')

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    212                 else:
    213                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 214             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    215 
    216         return cast(F, wrapper)

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression)
    606         return json_reader
    607 
--> 608     result = json_reader.read()
    609     if should_close:
    610         filepath_or_buffer.close()

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read(self)
    729             obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data.split("\n")))
    730         else:
--> 731             obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
    732         self.close()
    733         return obj

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _get_object_parser(self, json)
    751         obj = None
    752         if typ == "frame":
--> 753             obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
    754 
    755         if typ == "series" or obj is None:

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in parse(self)
    855 
    856         else:
--> 857             self._parse_no_numpy()
    858 
    859         if self.obj is None:

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1087         if orient == "columns":
   1088             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1089                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1090             )
   1091         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The error very clearly states these aren't JSON formatted, because you have `{'work'` and JSON would be `{"work"`, single quotes vs. double quotes.
- Using `.replace("'", '"')` will not work because the value of `'comment'` is properly double quoted (`"..."`), because there are words with an apostrophe (e.g. `"...father's..."`). Using replace, will produce a result like `'...father"s...'`.
- You have a file, with rows of `dicts`.
- The file needs to be read in, which will convert each row to a `str` type
- Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert each row back to a `dict` type
- Read the list of dicts, `rows`, into a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
from pathlib import Path

# read file
file = Path('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/test.json')  # path to file
with file.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # open the file
    rows = [literal_eval(row) for row in f.readlines()]  # list comprehension to convert each row back to a dict

# convert rows to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

# display(df)
       work flags    unixtime  stars  nhelpful          time                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              comment       user
0   2505753    []  1260403200    1.0         0  Dec 10, 2009  I really thought that I would like this book. I'm fascinated by this time period, and the plots to assassinate Hitler have always intrigued me. However, this book was so boring that I had to force myself to read it. The author no doubt has a commanding vocabulary, but his writing style and word choices made the book a chore to read. I've read dry textbooks that had more life to them than this novel.     schatzi
1  12458291    []  1361664000    4.0         0  Feb 24, 2013                   After her father's death, Lena discovers that her father had been keeping many secrets from her. Lena is a member of the. Silenti, telepaths who came to our world through a portal. She must learn to navigate through the social, religious, and political pitfalls of her new life. Who can she trust? What will her role be? I enjoyed this story and the world the author created very much.   aztwinmom
```

Comment: Thank You Sensei, you helped me big time, I'll make sure to quote my issues in a better way from next time, but really thank you! @trenton-mckinney